"Error: No Output Directory named 'build' found in Vercel deployment for React app
I am trying to deploy a full-stack app (Node.js backend and React frontend) on Vercel. However, I keep encountering the error:
mathematica
Copy code
Error: No Output Directory named "build" found after the Build completed. You can configure the Output Directory in your Project Settings.
{
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "backend/app.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        },
        {
            "src": "frontend/package.json",
            "use": "@vercel/static-build",
            "config": {
                "distDir": "frontend/build"  // This is where your build folder is located
            }
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/api/(.*)",
            "dest": "/backend/app.js"
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/frontend/build/$1"
        }
    ]
}


{
    "name": "frontend",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.13.3",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.13.0",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^6.1.0",
        "@mui/material": "^6.1.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "axios": "^1.7.7",
        "chart.js": "^4.4.4",
        "d3": "^7.9.0",
        "react": "^18.3.1",
        "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
        "react-d3-library": "^1.1.8",
        "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.26.2",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}

Despite this, the deployment fails due to the missing build directory. I’ve already run npm run build in the frontend, and the build folder is created locally. How can I ensure Vercel uses the correct output directory during deployment?

I have the same issue and I modified the vercel.json file changed "builds",
    "config": {
      "distDir": "build"
    }

And "routes",
  {
    "src": "/(.*)",
    "dest": "/frontend/$1"
  }

Good luck !!!

I have followed this, and now my functions are loading but only first page loads for frontend and for the rest i get 404.
